# What happens after testflight delivered app is released to app store

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

We had external testers testing our app through test flight.  Then we sent it off for Apple to approve.  Testers are not getting notified that the app is published (I'm assuming this is right since they already have the latest version).  If they go into test flight, it says the app will expire in 18 days.  Do we need to tell them to do anything about the expiring app, or is TestFlight reporting something that isn't true?  Will they have problems after their testing period expires?

Comment: Following common sense, they will need to download the app from the Store. The current one they have installed is only for testing purposes and should be replaced by the one in the Store.

Comment: Is any existing app data lost when the released version is downloaded from the Store?  In other words, is the test version actually deleted and the download treated as a new install, or does the download just update the existing version?

Comment: @MarionMcKelvie I know your question is an old one. I can confirm that data is not lost with respect to core data and user defaults. This assumes the bundle ID for the app is the same for both the test and release apps. If using core data, make sure you enable some sort of migration if your model is different between testing and release apps.

Answer (score 2):

Well, basically it's as follow: after **90 days** the Test Flight App will be disabled. They'll not be able to download it anymore, as it will expire. However if you've published your app to the App Store, they can easily download the newest version from there, that does not have an expiration date. They'll however not be notified that the app was released in the App Store as those are two separate processes. What you can do is when you have a new build, upload the new version to test flight and send them the new version for beta testing, which again will be available for 30 days before expiring.

Builds remain active for 90 days after upload.

[Your TestFlight app users should not be able to launch the app 90 days after you release](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/)

Hope that helps,
Julian

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options.  1) Tell the testers to download it from the app store or 2) push a new build to test flight which they can update to.

After 30 days the app goes Kaput!  We had this error where I was trying to track down a mysterious crash on somebody's phone when we realized they were still running a defunct test flight build.